# Accessing information from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary and this is the first part (it's very large)

```
           {'cluster-1': {'BGCid': '-',
           'cdhitclusters': [{'genes': {'AT1G24070': 100.0},
                              'rep_gene': 'AT1G24070'},
                             {'genes': {'AT1G24100': 100.0},
                              'rep_gene': 'AT1G24100'},
                             {'genes': {'AT1G24040': 100.0,
                                        'AT1G2404_1': 100.0,
                                        'AT1G2404_2': 100.0},
                              'rep_gene': 'AT1G24040'},
                             {'genes': {'AT1G24020': 100.0,
                                        'AT1G2402_1': 100.0},
                              'rep_gene': 'AT1G24020'},
                             {'genes': {'AT1G24010': 100.0},
                              'rep_gene': 'AT1G24010'},
                             {'genes': {'AT1G24000': 100.0},
                              'rep_gene': 'AT1G24000'}],
```

I want to print the information held by the key(?) 'rep_gene'. But it says rep_gene isn't a key.
What is rep_gene and how can I make a dataframe holding the rep_gene information?

**EDIT**

The first 2 lines work but the final one returns: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

```
clus1 = (gene_clusters.get("cluster-1"))
cdhit1 = (clus1.get("cdhitclusters"))
cdhit1.get("rep_gene")
```

Comment: Could you show us the indexes you are trying to use?

Comment: @DownloadPizza could you tell me how to do that please? I'm very new to this

Comment: Just post the code that throws an error, I think I can figure it out

Comment: I think that's what you're asking for, please clarify if not

Comment: Yes I got it, thanks, will post answer soon

Answer (score 1):

Your `cdhit1` contains the following list:

```json
[
   {
      "genes":{
         "AT1G24070":100.0
      },
      "rep_gene":"AT1G24070"
   },
   {
      "genes":{
         "AT1G24100":100.0
      },
      "rep_gene":"AT1G24100"
   },
   {
      "genes":{
         "AT1G24040":100.0,
         "AT1G2404_1":100.0,
         "AT1G2404_2":100.0
      },
      "rep_gene":"AT1G24040"
   },
   {
      "genes":{
         "AT1G24020":100.0,
         "AT1G2402_1":100.0
      },
      "rep_gene":"AT1G24020"
   },
   {
      "genes":{
         "AT1G24010":100.0
      },
      "rep_gene":"AT1G24010"
   },
   {
      "genes":{
         "AT1G24000":100.0
      },
      "rep_gene":"AT1G24000"
   }
]
```

So you need to specify which index you want to use. I have never worked with pandas, but maybe try `cdhit1[0]` and see what it returns. As you may notice you have multiple elements with `"rep_gene"` as key.

Comment: Yes, so how can I count the number of times rep_gene appears in the list? I've tried ```cdhit1.count(rep_gene)``` and it returns 1

Comment: Your elements contain the key rep_gene every time, dont they? I don't quite understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sometimes there are multiple genes for every rep_gene. I just want to count how many rep_genes there are. I have 44 clusters like this and I want to be able to say how many rep_genes there are per cluster.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a dataframe and counting the number of rows.
```rep1 = pd.DataFrame(cdhit1)
len(rep1.rep_gene)```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `Counter` from the built-in `collections` package:

```
# use list-of-dict from above
cd_hit_clusters = [
{'genes': {'AT1G24070': 100.0}, 'rep_gene': 'AT1G24070'}, 
{'genes': {'AT1G24100': 100.0}, 'rep_gene': 'AT1G24100'}, 
{'genes': {'AT1G24040': 100.0, 'AT1G2404_1': 100.0, 'AT1G2404_2': 100.0}, 'rep_gene': 'AT1G24040'}, 
{'genes': {'AT1G24020': 100.0, 'AT1G2402_1': 100.0}, 'rep_gene': 'AT1G24020'}, 
{'genes': {'AT1G24010': 100.0}, 'rep_gene': 'AT1G24010'}, 
{'genes': {'AT1G24000': 100.0}, 'rep_gene': 'AT1G24000'}
]
```

Now use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
rep_gene_list = [ cd['rep_gene'] for cd in cd_hit_clusters ]
Counter(rep_gene_list)

# results
Counter({'AT1G24070': 1,
         'AT1G24100': 1,
         'AT1G24040': 1,
         'AT1G24020': 1,
         'AT1G24010': 1,
         'AT1G24000': 1})
```